# How to show message depending on presence or absence of records?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to generate my report using a stored procedure (Oracle). What I want to display is if the procedure is executed, I want the end of the report message to be *"End of the report for "specified year""* and if there isn't any data at all, I want to display *"NO Record for "specified year""*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE booking_pending_report(in_month IN NUMBER,in_year IN NUMBER) AS

cursor pending_booking_basedondate_cursor is 
    select bo.journeystatus As "Journey Status",bo.bookingdate As "Booking Date",bo.fromdestination As "Location From",bo.todestination As "Desired Location", co.customerid As "Customer ID", co.customername As "Customer Name", co.customertel AS "Customer Phone No", concat(TRUNC((SYSDATE - TO_DATE(co.customerdob, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))/ 365.25),' years old') as "Customer Age", co.customergender as "Gender"
    from booking bo, customer co
    where bo.journeystatus = 'Pending' and bo.bookingdate between to_date('01-'||in_month||'-'||in_year,'dd-mm-yyyy') AND to_date('30-'||in_month||'-'||in_year,'dd-mm-yyyy') and bo.customerid = co.customerid
    group by bo.journeystatus, bo.fromdestination,bo.todestination, bo.bookingdate, co.customerid, co.customername, co.customertel, co.customerdob, co.customergender
    order by bookingdate;


pending_booking_basedondate_record pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%ROWTYPE;
v_count number(2);
v_countforchecking number(2);

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',30)||rpad('ON DEMAND REPORT',34)); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',6)||'Booking that are still on "Pending" in year '||in_year); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------');


OPEN pending_booking_basedondate_cursor;
v_count:=1;
v_countforchecking :=0;

Loop
 fetch pending_booking_basedondate_cursor into pending_booking_basedondate_record;

  if pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%NOTFOUND and v_countforchecking = 1 then
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',23)||'End of RECORD for the year '||in_year||'!!!');
   CLOSE pending_booking_basedondate_cursor;
   EXIT;
  elsif pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%NOTFOUND then
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',23)||'NO RECORD for the year '||in_year||'!!!');
  CLOSE pending_booking_basedondate_cursor;
  EXIT;
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('('||v_count||')'||' Customer ('||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Customer Name"||')');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Booking Status               :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Journey Status");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Booking Date                 :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Booking Date");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Location From                :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Location From");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Location From                :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Desired Location");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Age                 :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Customer Age");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Phone number        :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Customer Phone No");
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Gender              :'||pending_booking_basedondate_record."Gender");
  v_count:=v_count+1;
  v_countforchecking := v_countforchecking+1;
 end if;
END Loop;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',30)||'END OF REPORT'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'); 
END;
/
```

I want my report to be something like this (if there are records):

```
SQL> exec booking_pending_report(3,2021)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             ON DEMAND REPORT
.     Booking that are still on "Pending" in year 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
(1) Customer (Hollee)
--------------------------------------------------
Booking Status               :Pending
Booking Date                 :22/MAR/2021
Location From                :Kedah
Location From                :Pahang
Customer Age                 :31 years old
Customer Phone number        :013-5941276
Customer Gender              :Female
--------------------------------------------------
(2) Customer (Casey)
--------------------------------------------------
Booking Status               :Pending
Booking Date                 :24/MAR/2021
Location From                :Perak
Location From                :Johor
Customer Age                 :21 years old
Customer Phone number        :016-3818244
Customer Gender              :Female
.                     **End OF RECORD** for the year 2021!!!
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             END OF REPORT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the output kept giving me this result:

```
SQL> exec booking_pending_report(3,2021)

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             ON DEMAND REPORT
.     Booking that are still on "Pending" in year 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
(1) Customer (Hollee)
--------------------------------------------------
Booking Status               :Pending
Booking Date                 :22/MAR/2021
Location From                :Kedah
Location From                :Pahang
Customer Age                 :31 years old
Customer Phone number        :013-5941276
Customer Gender              :Female
--------------------------------------------------
(2) Customer (Casey)
--------------------------------------------------
Booking Status               :Pending
Booking Date                 :24/MAR/2021
Location From                :Perak
Location From                :Johor
Customer Age                 :21 years old
Customer Phone number        :016-3818244
Customer Gender              :Female
.                      **NO RECORD** for the year 2021!!! >> it doesn't make sense as there is a record
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             END OF REPORT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I only wanna display the no record when:

```
SQL> exec booking_pending_report(3,2028)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             ON DEMAND REPORT
.     Booking that are still on "Pending" in year 2028
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                      **NO RECORD** for the year 2028!!!
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
.                             END OF REPORT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my if else statement within the loop!

Comment: maybe this helps: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php

Comment: The statement is evaluated for each fetch. The statement is printed because there is one more fetch (which produces the 'not found' **after** the last record).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but i prevented that on my first if statement wasnt it? I just wondering why isnt that being excecuted!

Comment: Say you have two records, the first fetch finds a record, so it is displayed, the second fetch finds a record, so it is displayed, the third fetch doesn't find a record and v_count_for_checking is 2 (not 1), so it triggers the second if.

Comment: OMGGG! huge thanks to you, it workkssssss. Thank you for explaining the floww! Appreciated deeply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where you have made your bloomer.

```
if pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%NOTFOUND and v_countforchecking = 1 then
```

Your cursor returns two records, consequently
`v_countforchecking` does not equal `1` and so control moves to the `elsif` condition; that just checks for `pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%NOTFOUND`, which is true.

The first condition should check for

```
if pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%NOTFOUND and v_countforchecking >= 1 then
```

Answer (score 2):

@APC already answered to your question. But you can consider another maybe more efficient way of creating the same report.

```
DECLARE
    -- ALL OTHER VARIABLES

    v_counter INTEGER := 0;
    type t_booking_type is table of pending_booking_basedondate_cursor%rowtype;
    t_booking t_booking_type;

    cst_bulk_size CONSTANT INTEGER := 100;
    
BEGIN
    -- YOUR CODE
OPEN pending_booking_basedondate_cursor;

LOOP
    FETCH pending_booking_basedondate_cursor BULK COLLECT INTO t_booking LIMIT cst_bulk_size;
    
    FOR i IN 1..t_booking.COUNT() LOOP

        v_counter := v_counter + 1;
        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('('||v_counter||')'||' Customer ('||t_booking(i)."Customer Name"||')');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Booking Status               :'||t_booking(i)."Journey Status");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Booking Date                 :'||t_booking(i)."Booking Date");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Location From                :'||t_booking(i)."Location From");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Location From                :'||t_booking(i)."Desired Location");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Age                 :'||t_booking(i)."Customer Age");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Phone number        :'||t_booking(i)."Customer Phone No");
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Customer Gender              :'||t_booking(i)."Gender");
    END LOOP;   
    EXIT WHEN t_employees.COUNT() <> cst_bulk_size;
  
END LOOP;

IF t_employees.COUNT() <> 0 THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',23)||'End of RECORD for the year '||in_year||'!!!');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',23)||'NO RECORD for the year '||in_year||'!!!');
END IF;

CLOSE pending_booking_basedondate_cursor;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('.',30)||'END OF REPORT'); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------'); 

END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, ill give it a try later and update here of theres any question of mine to ask you! :D